# Django set record in custom order

Tags: python, django

how to set custom order of record in queryset?
ex:
Queryset has this values

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 5, 'order_number': 1}, {'id': 3, 'order_number': 2}, {'id': 2, 'order_number': 3}, {'id': 1, 'order_number': 4}, {'id': 7, 'order_number': 5}, {'id': 4, 'order_number': 6}]>
```

the request set the order of item of `id=5` to be 3rd record of the queryset
so the queryset should be:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'order_number': 1}, {'id': 2, 'order_number': 2}, {'id': 5, 'order_number': 3}, {'id': 1, 'order_number': 4}, {'id': 7, 'order_number': 5}, {'id': 4, 'order_number': 6}]>
```

I Could **loop over all the queryset** items and set the order every time, but I am asking if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order_by()`. This sorts the response in the database before sending it to Django, and is generally faster than writing your own sorting code.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

This sorts by `pub_date` in descending order (that's what the `-` does), then, if there's a tie, it sorts alphabetically by the headline.

In your example, I would add `.order_by('order_number')` to the queryset.

[More information about order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: hello Nick, thanks for your answer but I think I couldn't explain what I want in clear way. Imagine that you are user and have list of items and you want to make the 3rd item in the list be the first item in the returned list. so you will make request to the server with {item_id: 3, order_number: 1} so I should make the item 3 be in be the first item in the returned list in the next queries.

Comment: then using ```.order_by('order_number')```.

Comment: @AhmedSamy I don't think I understand what you're asking. Your followup seems to contradict the original example given. I'd suggest providing more detail in that example, or providing some working code so others can tell what you're trying to do.